# I was building an irc bot with the stackapps api and...

Tags: discussion

So I was building an irc bot from scratch. I had named it sobot. Did the first test run and guess what? There's already an irc bot by that name. So what I am asking is: Am i paddling in the wrong direction? Cause currently I do not find any irc bot in the apps section of the site.

Comment: by 'irc bot' you mean?

Comment: well its a bot that will run on an irc channel. And do stuff with the stackapps api.

Comment: Awesome! I'd love to hear more about this... is it going to be open-source? What language is it in?

Comment: sure it will be open source. it's in python though. So i guess im gonna hear some "bleh" out there :D

Comment: I love Python. I even used it for one of my API apps. No complaints from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't seen any mention of an irc bot here.

<strike>perhaps the name is coincidental.</strike>

Apparently is is not coincidental.

Can you beat it? if so - go for it. competition creates better software.

Comment: a /whois gives the description as "Stack overflow question bot" :/

Comment: whois...? whois of what...?

Comment: @theplic - updated answer

Comment: I came to know about this comp this week. Just started out. Though I will finish what i started anyway.
@George It's an irc command to know about a user.

Comment: Ooooh. *That* whois. (I was thinking of a different one.)